# In OSX accessing (optional?) property "identifier" of NSView subclass leads to bad access

Tags: macos, swift, option-type

Since I am fairly new to Swift programming on OSX, this question may contain several points that needs clarification.

I have a method which iterates over all subviews of a given `NSView` instance. For this, I get the array of subviews which is of type `[AnyObject]` and process one element at a time.

At some point I would like to access the `identifier` property of each instance. This property is implemented from a protocol in NSView named `NSUserInterfaceItemIdentification`, which type is given in the documentation as (optional) `String?`. In order to get that identifier I would have written

```
var view : NSView = subview as NSView;
var viewIdent : String = view.identifier!;
```

The second line is marked by the compiler with an error stating that `identifier` is not of an optional type, but instead of type `String`, and hence the post-fix operator `!` cannot be applied.

Removing this operator compiles fine, but leads to a runtime error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` because `identifier` seems to be `nil` for some `NSButton` instance.

I cannot even test for this property, because the compiler gives me a `String is not convertible to UInt8` while I try

```
if (view.identifier != nil) {viewIdent = view.identifier;}
```

My questions are

1. Is the documentation wrong? I.g. the property `identifier` is not optional?
2. How can I ship around this problem and get code that runs robust?

Answer (score 0):

If the documentation states that `view.identifier` is an Optional, it means it can be nil. So it's not a surprise that for some button instances it is indeed nil for you.

Force unwrapping this element that can be nil will lead your app to crash, you can use safe unwrapping instead:

```
if let viewIdent = view.identifier {
    // do something with viewIdent
} else {
    // view.identifier was nil
}
```

You can easily check the type of an element in Xcode: click on the element while holding the ALT key. It will reveal a popup with informations, including the type. You can verify there that your element is an Optional or not.

Tip: you can safe unwrap several items on one line, it's rather convenient:

```
if let view = subview as? NSView, viewIdent = view.identifier {
    // you can do something here with `viewIdent` because `view` and `view.identifier` were both not nil
} else {
    // `view` or `view.identifier` was nil, handle the error here
}
```

**EDIT:**

You have to remove this line of yours before using my example:

```
var viewIdent : String = view.identifier!
```

Because if you keep this line before my examples, it won't work because *you* transform what was an Optional in a non-Optional by adding this exclamation mark.

Also it forces casting to a String, but maybe your `identifier` is an Int instead, so you shouldn't use this kind of declaration but prefer `if let ...` to safe unwrap and cast the value.

**EDIT2:**

You say my example doesn't compile... I test *every* answer I make on SO. I tested this one in a Playground before answering, here's a screenshot:

[image]

**Also, after checking it, I confirm that the identifier is an Optional String, that's the type given by Xcode when using ALT+CLICK on the property. The documentation is right.**

So if it's different for you, it means you have a different problem unrelated to this one; but my answer for this precise question remains the same.

Comment: I get the error message `Bound value in a conditional binding must be of optional type.` at compile time. Again, the compiler thinks it is not an optional, which should ensure that at runtime there is no `nil` value assigned to a variable, but the runtime has to deal with an optional (in this case `nil`) value.

Comment: Also, be careful of the possible confusion: if you *declare* an Optional as a non-Optional like you did here: `var viewIdent : String = view.identifier!` then it **will** crash if the identifier is nil, because *you* transformed the Optional in a non-Optional. :)

Comment: Regarding your edit: I never used that line that you mention. If you read my whole question, you realise that this line does not compile on my machine. The same is with your example lines above your Edit mark, they do not compile neither. I've got the feeling that my problem is not to get an optional value unwrapped, but to find out why (maybe only) my system behaves this way. To me the most obvious problem is the mismatch between Apple's documentation and the type as it is known to the compiler. Do you have any ideas how I can find out what is wrong?

Comment: See EDIT2 in my answer. Also, I've read your whole question, thank you very much. :/

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to rude. I'm sorry for that. What I was trying to express is that your efforts were heading in the wrong direction. While I am pretty sure about how to unwrap an optional and test the presence of a value, I was wondering about the behaviour of the compiler despite the documentation for the property we are talking about. My question about robustness was more about a hunch that I might be missing some really fundamental detail, a third kind of property.

Comment: For your second edit: ALT+mouse-click revealed a type of the property which is just String, no optional. Thanks for that hint! Do you have any ideas how I can figure out how to fix this?

Comment: I also apologize, I may have been a bit touchy, sorry for that. // In my test Playground, the property was a String but an Optional. Very strange. If indeed (figure of speech, I believe you) you don't use the infamous `var viewIdent : String = view.identifier!` declaration, I don't see why the type is different for you and, no, I have no solution because I can't reproduce this behaviour yet.